# How can I use one SSL certificate to secure multiple, dynamic, EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I am working with an application deployed on AWS EC2. One head instance, www.me.com, provides login & admin such that a user can spawn an instance of the application. A new AWS EC2 instance is started to run the application, then the user's browser is redirected to that instance (with long URL ending amazonaws.com), and the application is available until the user closes it (then the EC2 instance is stopped).

We now wish to move the application to use SSL. We can get a certificate from some CA, and tie it to *.me.com. The question is, how do we use the same certificate to secure the application instances?

One idea is to use Elastic IP - we reserve N IPs, and tie N sub-domains (foo1.me.com, foo2, ...) to these. Then we start each application instance associated with one of these, and direct the user to the associated sub-domain. Certificate is valid, all is well. I think this works?

Trouble is, the application should scale to 1000's of simultaneous users, but may well spend the majority of time bouncing along around zero users, so we'll pay significant penalty costs for reserving the unused IPs, and besides, we might exceed N and have to deny access.

Simpler, perhaps, would be to provide access to the application routed through the head server, www.me.com, using either of "a.me.com" or "www.me.com/a". The former, I think doesn't work, because it would need the DNS records to be updated to be useful to the user, which cannot happen quickly enough to be offered to a user on the fly. The latter might work, but I don't know web infrastructure well enough to imagine how to engineer it. Even if we were only serving port 80, and in fact we are also providing services on other ports. So we'd need something like:

```
www.me.com/a:80 <--> foo.amazonaws.com:80
www.me.com/a:8001 <--> foo.amazonaws.com:8001
www.me.com/a:8002 <--> foo.amazonaws.com:8002
...
```

It seems to me there are two options, either a head server that handles all traffic (under me.com, and thus under the certificate) and somehow hands it off to the application instances, or some method for allowing the users to connect directly to the application instances but in such a way that we can reasonably manage securing these connections using one (or a small number of) certificates.

Can anyone suggest what is the route one way to do this? I'm assuming it's not Route 53, since - again - that's a DNS thing, with DNS lag. Unless I've misunderstood.

Thanks.

Comment: Is all the traffic HTTP/S traffic, even when it's on another port?

Comment: No, all is either http/s or ws/s.

Comment: Put an ALB in front of it... You can add the wildcard card certificate to the ALB and direct your DNS to the ALB and the ALB will forward the traffic to target group which will contain your EC2 instances.